# How to fix this powershell ParserError?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script (version 2.0) to send inline images, as [explained here](http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/). But something does not seem to work, or is maybe outdated or incorrect.

The following is a complete test script

```
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

$image = "testImage.png"
$imageFull = "D:\Testing\testImage.png"

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment  –ArgumentList $imageFull

$body=@"
<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:$image">
</body>
</html>
"@
```

which only uses an example image, and creates the following error:

```
The string starting:
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRtestError.ps1:14 char:1
+  <<<< "@
is missing the terminator: ".
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRtestError.ps1:16 char:1
+  <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (@

:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

What is going on? Why is this error created? How to fix it?

NOTE:

- If you comment out the `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` line, no error is created!!
- Used OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit)
- Full version table:

  ```
  $psversiontable:

  Name                           Value
  ----                           -----
  CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
  BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
  PSVersion                      2.0
  WSManStackVersion              2.0
  PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
  SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
  ```

  PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

Comment: I ran your script on a server with the same version of powershell as yours and it ran without any problem. How do you execute the script?

Comment: On a powershell commandline (`Windows PowerShell (x86)`) as administrator. I change into the directory containinf the script and then I start it as `.\testscript.ps1`.

Comment: Something is fishy. The error states that the string starting in line 14 has no terminator (your script seems to have two more lines though). This means the quotation mark before the @ on line 14 is a opening mark and not a closing one. Thus I guess you have somewhere in the actual script one surplus quotation mark. Most likely in the line 6 with System.Net.Mail.Attachment. This would also explain why omitting this line results in a faultless execution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `@"` are the first characters, and `"@` are last characters on the line. And that assigning the variable has it's own line `$body=@"`. The code runs fine for me.

More information about these "Here-Strings" can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx)

```
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

$image = "testImage.png"
$imageFull = "D:\Testing\testImage.png"

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $imageFull

$body=@"
<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:$image">
</body>
</html>
"@
```

Comment: `@"` must be last, and `"@` must be ***first*** (not last)

Comment: I guess `"@` must be _first_ **and** _last_. I get errors trying inserting anything before or after.

Comment: You can have statements following the terminator, no problem: https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/e2f7ed95e5837c57df8ff5d44c7146fc#file-here-string-ps1

Comment: I get the exact same error. It looks like the same code. The code still fails for me.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a [different quotation mark](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None)?

Comment: I copied the script from the answer. Should I attach a screenshot... or a ASCII list??

Comment: If you copied it directly then indeed that shouldn't be a problem. As your and my code run fine for me, I'm trying to look at alternative problems.

Comment: Maybe I am using a strange version of Powershell? I have updated the question with the complete version table ...

Comment: And why does the line before play an important role? What is going on in the attachment line?

Comment: Switching to version 2, I have the exact same PSVersionTable. Runs fine for me with and without the attachment line. Perhaps try an alternative notation? `$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($imageFull)`